# Airflow rerun of subdag operator while other subdag operators are running

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I am using airflow 1.9.0 with the LocalExecutor.

I have a subdag containing two long-running tasks. The structure of the subdag is:

```
def create_subdag(name_suffix, default_args):
    dag_name = '{}.{}'.format(parent_dag_name, name_suffix)
    subdag = DAG(dag_name, start_date=start, schedule_interval=schedule, default_args=default_args)

    t1 = BashOperator(
        task_id='print_date',
        bash_command='some_long_running_cmd_1',
        dag=subdag)

    t2 = BashOperator(
        task_id='sleep',
        bash_command='some_long_running_cmd_2',
        dag=subdag)

sub_dag_1 = SubDagOperator(
    subdag=create_subdag('subdag1', default_args),
    task_id='subdag1',
    dag=dag)
```

I would like to be able to re-run task t2 when it fails even if task t1 is still running. Normally, clearing the status of a failed task causes it to get re-scheduled, even if other tasks in the dag are running. However, clearing the status of task t2 does not get it re-scheduled. Furthermore, clearing the status of sub_dag_1 while it is still running seems to get the scheduler into a hung state where the DAG never transitions out of `running` even after t2 completes, but `t1` is never rescheduled for execution.

Is there a way to re-run a task in the subdag immediately without waiting for the other tasks to complete?

Comment: Can you try seeing if the same thing is possible without using subdags? Make sure your task can be done with a regular dag before trying to port it over into a subdag.

Comment: @VirajParekh I can implement this particular workflow without subdags. This is more of a general question whether independent subdag operator re-runs are possible. If they are not, I will probably avoid the use of subdags altogether even in case where they would otherwise be appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

I have the following possible solutions:

1. In your subdag, try clear `t2` first and then manually re-run t2 independently
2. Usually when `sub_dag_1` finished (either ended up in a successful state of failure state), then clear `t2` will automatically re-trigger the t2 to run.
3. If you still wanna `t2` to re-run given `t1` is still running and `sub_dag_1` is running too, make `sub_dag_1` as success (non-recursively). then repeat 2.

Hopefully, this will help you. BTW, `SubDagOperator` is not a very good operator to use in real world application, based on my experiences, it add more issues (e.g., subdag [deadlock](https://medium.com/@team_24989/fixing-subdagoperator-deadlock-in-airflow-6c64312ebb10), celery workers become slow to pick up subdag tasks. etc) compared to the problem it solved.